# How to allow hyphens in htaccess rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am having problems creating clean urls containing a hyphen.

I want the url to be `/services/baking-cake`, and I would like to redirect to the version of the url without a trailing slash.

My .htaccess now has these rules:

```
RewriteRule services/(.*)/ services/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule services/(.*) services.php?page=$1
```

This works fine for the query-string `baking`, but not for `baking-cake`. In that case, when a trailing slash is added, it jumps to:

```
/services.php/baking-cake?page=baking-cake/
```

How do I change the match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need is these 2 simple rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^services/(.*)/?$ services.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: While that does make the url work, it doesn't redirect the url with a trailing slash to the one without. Do I need something else?